# vb.net program to register time on multiple runners

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I building a program to track the time of up to 60 runners. My idea is to use a `DataGridView` with columns for:

- 1. ID (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)
- 2. Name (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)
- 3. Start time (DataGridViewButtonColumn)
- 4. Stop time (DataGridViewButtonColumn)
- 5. Reset time (DataGridViewButtonColumn)
- 6. Finish time (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)

Adding columns 1-5 including functions is no problem, but I cannot wrap my head around how to display a stopwatch in column 6.

My idea was to add a timer and stopwatch function every time a new row I added, but do I need a timer for each row? If so how do I set the ID of that timer, so I can call the Tick event and display the time in column 6?

Also I assume that I need a stopwatch for each row? So how do I set the name of ID of each Stopwatch - can seem to find any property for that?

See below screen shot of what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks in advance.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHYaL.png)

Comment: You could have a `List(Of Timer)`?

Comment: Hi @AlexM. Can you elaborate? I have never used Timer before, so unsure of list of timers.